# Creating an atoi function

Tags: c, function, atoi

I'm attempting to create my own atoi function. With the following I'm getting a return value of 0. Whatever I change the number variable within the function is what I get as a return value. Any suggestions on modifying the code?

```
//my atoi function
int atoi_me(char *numstring)
{
    int number = 0;
    while((*numstring >= '0') && (*numstring <= '9'))
    {
        number = (number * 10) + (*numstring - '0');
        numstring++;
    }

    return number;
}

int main()
{
    char *number[MAXSIZE];
    int num;

    printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%c", &number);
    num = atoi_me(*number);
    printf("%d", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you using as input?

Comment: The expression `number = (number * 10)` will always be `0`.

Comment: @htor, only the first time.

Comment: @KryptNick, are you sure this is your real code?  It looks fine to me, and works well in a test program here.  What input are you using?

Comment: Looks okay to me. Don't you have a debugger handy?

Comment: I tried it and it worked ok.

Comment: It should work, what's the string you're passing to it?

Comment: try number = (number * 10) + ((int)(*numstring - '0'));

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, can you provide some problematic input examples?

Comment: @infested, that typecast won't do anything.  `*numstring` and `'0'` are both already promoted to `int` before the subtraction takes place. OP's code is fine, it's his input that must be wrong.

Comment: I'm passing a char pointer from the main function. I'm going to try to run in in a different compiler.

Comment: Unless you are passing something like "+1234" or "-1234" or " 1234" (i.e. the leading char is not a digit) - your program should work fine. What's your input? Paste your function call ine - that's likely the problem

Comment: int main()
{
    char *number[MAXSIZE];
    int num;

    printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%c", &number);

    num = atoi_me(*number);
    printf("%d", num);

    return 0;

}

Comment: @KryptNick, a different compiler won't make any difference.  Your program is perfectly acceptable standard C code.  Can you please show your `main()` routine?  Maybe we can help you find your bug there.

Comment: `char number[MAXSIZE]`and `scanf("%s", number)`and `atoi_me(number)`

Comment: Please edit that `main` back into your original question.  The problem is indeed there.

Comment: wont %c get only one char? and why du have char *number[] as 2D array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You're declaring an array of `char *`, that is, an array of strings, rather than a single string.  You probably want:

   ```
   char number[MAXSIZE];
   ```
2. Your `scanf` format string is wrong.  If you want to read a string, you should use `%s`.  `%c` reads only a single character.
3. Your `scanf` parameter is wrong - pass `number` itself (or `&number[0]` if you prefer), not `&number`.
4. The parameter you're passing to `atoi_me` is wrong.  Call it with `number` (or equivalently `&number[0]`), not `*number`.

Putting all of that together, you should have a `main` routine something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    char number[MAXSIZE];
    int num;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%s", number);
    num = atoi_me(number);
    printf("%d\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Editorial notes: You have a potential buffer overflow with the `scanf` line.  You'd be better off using a function like [`fgets(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/) that makes it easy to protect against that kind of problem.

[`atoi(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/atoi/) also traditionally supports negative numbers (with a leading `-`) and an optional leading `+` for positive numbers, which your implementation doesn't handle.

Comment: i think having number is ok, as scanf wants a ref to the variable no?

Comment: @Infested, `number` is an array and so decays to a pointer to its first element when used in this context.  I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Infested, then I really don't understand.  That's what my answer says, isn't it?

Comment: Hm, I don't remember writing anything different.  Maybe I corrected it somewhere along the way.

Comment: +1, this was the accepted answer, and it should still be. I didn't intend to steal it away.

Comment: Thanks @user315052.  No skin off my nose.

Comment: @Carl Norum Sorry I'm new to this site and thought I could pick more than one answer. Your answer did correct my problem

Answer (score 1):

As I thought, the problem is in your call.

Change your main to.

```
int main()
{
    char number[MAXSIZE];
    int num;

    printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%s", number);
    num = atoi_me(number);
    printf("%d", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Other than this it's not a good idea to use scanf - http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html . In this case you should use `fgets`.

Comment: @KryptNick - what do you mean 'locks up. Anyway, I had missed changing the atoi_me call. Changed it now after Carl Norum pointing it out.

Comment: sorry about that... it wouldn't continue into the function after the input. It simply crashed

Answer (score 1):

This was not an issue with your `atoi_me()` function, but an issue with how you obtained your input. Your implementation shows some weakness in your understanding of how `scanf()` works. That's not a problem in of itself, making mistakes is part of the learning process after all.

It is generally safer to gather your input into a buffer first, because `scanf()` from the standard input relies too much on the user of the program to type input exactly the way you expect it. In this case, there is not much harm since you only want a single line of input. But, usually, a program will process multiple lines of input, and `scanf()` can jam when an error occurs. So, you can use something like this to get your line of input instead:

```
char line[MAXLINESIZE];

if (fgets(line, MAXLINESIZE, stdin) == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "no input was provided!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned elsewhere, `%c` is the wrong format specifier to use for the input you are gathering. Since you want decimal digits, the `*scanf()` family has a format specifier to allow you to only collect those characters.

```
char number[MAXSIZE];

if (sscanf(line, " %[0-9]", number) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "no number found in input: %s", line);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, I use the `line` that was retrieved with `fgets()`, and parse out the part of the input that contains the digits. The leading space causes `sscanf()` to skip over space characters leading up to the digits.

Comment: Thanks for this post. I see that strong knowledge of library functions can definitely save headaches.

Comment: I didn't mean to steal the accepted answer from @CarlNorum. This information is supplemental to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `number` is supposed to be a char array,

- you should declare it as `char number[MAXSIZE];`,
- you shouldn't call your function with `&number` but with `number`, directly : `atoi_me(number);`

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

```
int atoi_me(const char *numstring)...
```

Better to use const type pointer, as you don't intend to modify string contents.

```
int main()
{
    char number[MAXSIZE]; // array of chars
    int num;

    printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%s", number);     // enter a string, not a char
    num = atoi_me(number);   // pointer to char, not pointer to pointer
    printf("%d", num);
    return 0;
}
```